# Zooming in and out on an image not working as it should

Tags: javascript

i have a map image that i want to zoom in and out on with the scrollwheel.
This works perfectly while zooming in or out only, but when i change direction (from to have zoomed in to zoom out) the shit starts.

If i scrolled 3 times zoom in and then change direction to zoom out it takes as many scrolls -1 before it starts zooming out and meanwhile it keeps zooming in making the ctx.scale go bananas.

Thank you for any replys <3

```
    var scaleY = 1;
    var scaleX = 1;

    //function to draw the map
     function loader(){

    //load background
     var canvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
     var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

     var background = new Image();
     background.src = "map2.png";
     background.onload = function(){
     ctx.clearRect(0,0,1375,850);
     ctx.scale(scaleY,scaleX);
     ctx.drawImage(background,0,0);
     ctx.font = "15px arial";
     ctx.fillText(scaleY,25,pos); 
     }
     }
    function userActions(){
    var canvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas");

    //detect scroll activity
    canvas.addEventListener("wheel", zoom);

     //function to decide if the scroll si up or down
      function zoom(e){
      if (e.deltaY < 0){
      //change the scale 
      scaleY = Math.round((scaleY + 0.1) * 10) / 10;
      scaleX = Math.round((scaleX + 0.1) * 10) / 10; 
      loader(scaleY, scaleX);
      } 
      if(e.deltaY > 0){
      //change the scale
      scaleY = Math.round((scaleY - 0.1) * 10) / 10;
      scaleX = Math.round((scaleX - 0.1) * 10) / 10;   
      loader(scaleY, scaleX);
      }

      }

      }
```

Comment: Probably should just load the image once and not every time you want to update the canvas. That's just an side though.

Comment: Yea that is a good idea, how ever it dosnt solve my problem, it is like the scroll value stacks upp, it is either -100 or 100, and the more i scroll in the more i gotta scrol out before it works. if i scroll in 2 times i gotta scroll out 2 times before it starts and when i scroll out it instead scrolls in, very weird...

Comment: Also, you call loader with the scale arguments, but loader does not use them. Should also not matter because the variables are in scope anyway.

Comment: I thank you for the input, and also for the shitty explanation. been bashing my head on this all day but cannot figure it out :S

Comment: For MY shitty explanation, that did not come out right xP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`scale` is not absolute, but multiplies the scale factors onto the current transformation matrix. You should reset it after every draw call. This can be done via:

```
ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
```

```js
var scaleY = 1;
var scaleX = 1;

var canvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var background = new Image();
background.src = "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/c35af79e54306caedad37141f13de30c?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG";
background.onload = draw;

//function to draw the map
function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.scale(scaleY, scaleX);
  ctx.drawImage(background, 0, 0);

  // reset current transformation matrix to the identity matrix
  ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
}

//function to decide if the scroll si up or down
function zoom(e) {
  if (e.deltaY < 0) {
    //change the scale 
    scaleY = Math.round((scaleY + 0.1) * 10) / 10;
    scaleX = Math.round((scaleX + 0.1) * 10) / 10;
    draw();
  }
  if (e.deltaY > 0) {
    //change the scale
    scaleY = Math.round((scaleY - 0.1) * 10) / 10;
    scaleX = Math.round((scaleX - 0.1) * 10) / 10;
    draw();
  }
  e.preventDefault();
}
canvas.addEventListener("wheel", zoom);
```

```html
<canvas id="mycanvas" height="200" width="200"/>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked perfectly, been pulling my hair on this one :D

Comment: You're welcome. I literally just looked up `scale` on MDN and the specification.